# How to make Apache server to respect new php.ini values after restarting it?

Tags: php, apache

I am trying to add error reporting to my php installation by adding the following line to the *`php.ini`*:

```
display_errors = On
```

Then I restart Apache server using the command:

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

Finally when I am running a `phpinfo()` function to see php installation details, I get the report that `display_errors` is **Off**.

Any ideas on what am I missing here?
Thank you.

Comment: are you sure you modded the right php.ini? there can be multiple of them, plus overrides all over the place OTHER than the php.ini which could be turning the setting off again.

Comment: phpinfo() should tell you the right one to edit; and `php -i` for cli

Comment: I used the php.ini file that I get from the phpinfo() report. (It is placed at /etc/php.ini)

Comment: The only code inside the php file that I run for the report is the phpinfo() function.

Comment: @nickhar : Thnx for editing it.It is more clear now (I also checked the raw post to learn how to do that properly)

Comment: @Dagon : php -i | grep display gives `display_errors => Off => Off`

Comment: I see now that php --ini gives another path : /usr/local/lib/php.ini . How can I decide which one of the two php.ini files is being used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is strange. Are you certain the changes to `/etc/php.ini` are saved?

Are there any other script running before you get to your page? It could be that errors are being turned off in one of those scripts. Also, have you checked the `php.ini` file to make sure `display_errors` only appears once?

Doesn't make sense on the surface - if you change the correct `php.ini` file to `display_errors = on` and restart Apache, error reporting should be turned on. Can you paste your script?

Comment: I should have checked it.The php.ini has two lines referring to display_errors and the first one is commented out, so when you alter the file you may miss the second one!